# Permission denied for laravel and docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laravel-9, php-8

I'm trying to create an image for laravel in docker but it is giving permission denied in a log folder.

```
The stream or file "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

My docker-compose

```
php:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
     - ./:/var/www/
     - laravel-log:/var/www/html/storage/
     - bootstrap-cache:/var/www/html/bootstrap/cache/
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

Docker file

```
FROM php:8-fpm
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/storage/framework/{sessions,views,cache} \
     && mkdir -p /var/www/bootstrap/cache \
     && mkdir -p /var/www/storage/logs \
     && chmod +w /var/www/storage/ \
     && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Comment: have you managed to complete the image build ?

Comment: Is it `/var/www/html/storage` or `/var/www/storage`?

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs as www-data(ID: 33) by default, so it makes perfect sense to change the owner to www-data. However, the files whose ownership you are changing are not inside docker, they are mounted outside the container. This means that whatever you make to those files, they'll still be owned by your local user (outside docker) with it's own UID.

In order to solve this issue, you need to ensure that docker uses the same owner for those files as they have ouside the container. There's no need to use the same name, just the same UID.

To achieve this, just add create a new user inside the container that matches the UID of your local user and use it instead of the default. This should work:

```
ENV PHP_UID=1000
ENV PHP_GID=1000
FROM php:8-fpm
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/storage/framework/{sessions,views,cache} \
    && mkdir -p /var/www/bootstrap/cache \
    && mkdir -p /var/www/storage/logs \
    && addgroup -g ${PHP_UID} www \
    && adduser -H -D -u ${PHP_GID} -G www www \
    && chown -R www:www /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www
USER www
```